# Why can't I award my bounty?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, bounty

This might be better for https://meta.stackexchange.com/ but someone here might know.

For my question [Musical Quines on an ASCII Piano](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37255/musical-quines-on-an-ascii-piano) I'm trying to award my bounty to this answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38224/26997.

I keep clicking the red +300 next to the answer and an alert pops up saying 'Are your sure...?', but when I click 'Yes' nothing happens. The bounty hasn't closed and has not been awarded.

Does anyone know what's going on? Am I missing some rule on bounty awarding?

The bounty closes in 4 hours. I'm using the latest Chrome if that helps.

Comment: Huh, strange. It could be a userscript interfering; try disabling all of those, going Incognito, or just using a different web browser.

Comment: @Doorknob Still not working in incognito mode or Firefox.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you know how to accept an answer, so how about that? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that, fixed now. Fortunately you still have ample time to answer the bounty (there's a grace period of 24 hours before the bounty is automatically closed).